# Use an OTF font for Greek text with pdfLaTeX

Tags: fonts, pdftex, greek, mathpazo, autoinst

I use (for several reasons) pdfLaTeX for compiling and URW Palladio as main font for the document, via the `mathpazo` package. Additionally, I want to include a small quote in Ancient Greek. Hence the document looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek,british]{babel}
\usepackage{mathpazo}

\begin{document}

Here is some text with Latin letters.

\textgreek{Μῆνιν ἄειδε θεὰ Πηληιάδεω Ἀχιλῆος οὐλομένην,\par
  ἥ μυρί’ Ἀχαιοῖς ἄλγε’ ἔθηκε.}

\end{document}
```

Now I would like to use for the Greek text a font that matches URW Palladio, and I was thinking of the Heraklit font, which is based on work of Hermann Zapf as well. [Here](https://fontesk.com/gfs-heraklit-font/) I found an OTF file for the font.

Of course, as I am using pdfLaTeX, I will have to install the font properly. I have already tried the easiest option, namely:

```
autoinst GFSHeraklit.otf
texhash
updmap-sys --enable Map GFSHeraklit.map
```

and then including the line

```
\renewcommand*{\rmfamily}{GFSHeraklit-TOsF}
```

right in front of the quote, but apparently, this was too naïve: it causes no error, but also no change at all. The same happens if I replace `\usepackage{mathpazo}` by `\usepackage{GFSHeraklit}`; here I guess that the package `GFSHeraklit` does the same to Latin letters as `mathpazo`, but apparently nothing to the Greek ones.

Does someone have an idea what my mistake is?

Comment: `\renewcommand*{\rmfamily}{GFSHeraklit-TOsF}` is simply wrong. It should be `\renewcommand*{\rmdefault}{GFSHeraklit-TOsF}`. Beside this I have some doubts that autoinst by default creates support for the LGR encoding.

Comment: Okay, thanks for pointing out this mistake! I have changed this line in my file, but the result stays the same. Maybe I have to use `otftotfm`? However, I don’t know enough about it in order to use it properly for LGR encoding.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you simply use the open type version??

Run with `lualatex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{GFSHeraklit.otf}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek,british]{babel}
\begin{document}

Here is some text with Latin letters.

Μῆνιν ἄειδε θεὰ Πηληιάδεω Ἀχιλῆος οὐλομένην,\par
  ἥ μυρί’ Ἀχαιοῖς ἄλγε’ ἔθηκε.

\end{document}
```

[image]

And the same with Pagella and GFSHeraklit for Greek:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeXGyrePagella}
\newfontface\textgreek{GFSHeraklit.otf}[AutoFakeBold]
\usepackage[polutonikogreek,british]{babel}
\begin{document}

Here is some text with Latin letters.

\textbf{Here is some text with Latin letters.}

\textgreek{Μῆνιν ἄειδε θεὰ Πηληιάδεω Ἀχιλῆος οὐλομένην,\par
  ἥ μυρί’ Ἀχαιοῖς ἄλγε’ ἔθηκε.

\textbf{ἥ μυρί’ Ἀχαιοῖς ἄλγε’ ἔθηκε.}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sure, this works. However, I really want to stick to pdflatex, since at the end, I don’t want to use it only in this MWE, but in my thesis. I once tried the TeX Gyre Pagella Math font (which, to some extend, replaces the mathpazo package in math mode) and reached several issues which vanish when using pdflatex and mathpazo. (Side remark: How can you use the usual Gyre Pagella font for the Latin text in your above example? For example, GFSHeraklit does not contain bold Latin letters, which I want to use outside of the Greek quote.)

Comment: `pdflatex` is depending to font using from the last century! And the only difference to `lualatex` is `fontenc`->`fontspec`. That's all. You can use PAgella as default font and define a `\textgreek` command or using the optional argument `AutoFakeBold` with `fontspec`.

Comment: @FKranhold “... and reached several issues which vanish when using pdflatex”: This sounds like an XY problem. Perhaps it would be better to solve those issues.